# Java API to create Shape from clipping path embedded in tif source file

Tags: java, image, image-processing, tiff, javax.imageio

Here is my situation.

I have a servlet that serves images. I used ImageIO SPI to add support for writing TGA-16 images because Java doesn't support TGA out of the box and unbelievably - TGA is still EXTREMELY prevalent in JDA Space Planning Software. I also used Apache Commons Imaging to support TIF images as well. Thank You @haraldK and @Johan for your much appreciated help.

The problem I face is adding support to transform TIF source images to other formats while retaining the Clipping Path. I have searched for months and found a way to do it with im4java, but my problem is that the servlet replaced ImageMagick and all dependencies along with the PHP scripts that use to serve images - so I would rather not go that route.

Does anybody know of a Java API that can be used to read the XML embedded in the TIF Header into a Java Shape and doesn't use ImageMagick under the covers?

Here is example Clipping Path XML embedded in Tiff Header:

Clipping path:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<svg width="1753" height="1800">
<g>
<path style="fill:#00000000;stroke:#00000000;stroke-width:0;stroke-antialiasing:false" d="
M 181.459 178.579
V 170.188 180.269 170.188 195.632
Y 170.188 210.994 170.188 1473.63
V 170.554 1491.5 176.721 1500.8
Y 208.469 1548.66 309.381 1683.47
V 331.175 1712.37 358.181 1708.11
Y 385.186 1703.84 1570.59 1559.64
V 1582.38 1559.84 1582.38 1545.63
Y 1582.38 1531.42 1582.38 234.474
V 1583.59 214.93 1574.31 207.599
C 1536.48 177.747 1484.3 147.104 1436.35 125.402
Y 1391.68 105.178 1351.71 93.7894
V 1339.86 90.4736 1321.86 91.8947
C 1315.75 92.377 1190.32 100.732 1024.36 114.142
C 1015.45 114.861 1007.86 121.442 998.722 122.04
C 869.146 130.514 726.84 140.18 595.638 148.72
C 578.398 149.842 551.936 143.832 535.282 144.912
Y 353.926 156.665 207.991 165.316
V 197.568 168.396 197.568 175.737
L 181.459 178.579 Z
"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

This is an embedded clipping path created by Photoshop.

Comment: You're welcome! ;-) What format does the XML use? Maybe you can link or include a short clipping-path XML example? Java2D does have pretty decent support for shapes and paths I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like [SVG](http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/) to me.

The most well-known and robust SVG library for Java is [Apache Batik](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/). It does, however, have a quite large footprint (loads of classes and JARs).

Have a look at [SVGSalamander](https://svgsalamander.java.net/), [TinyLine](http://www.tinyline.com/svgt/) or [JFreeSVG](http://www.jfree.org/jfreesvg/) if the size and performance of Batik is a concern (disclaimer: I've never used any of them).

Not exactly sure how these will render the SVG and how you will apply the rendered output to your image, but I think you might work it out.

Comment: I was thinking this was the way to go, but was unsure. And of course - I was hoping for an API that did it transparently - However, hoping doesn't get you too far in development. I have some work to do. Thanks again @haraldK

Comment: @JasonPalmer That would be nice. Feel free to file the functionality you'd like as an [new feature request](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys/issues) for my ImageIO TIFF plugin. Not making any promises, but I might look into it one day. :-)

Comment: I will happily plug @haraldK's powerful [ImageIO Plugins Library](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys/commit/77e660060511399fea1b9c23dc65af34f0aab7fd) The support has now been added to his library.